# Javascript file loads with no content

Tags: javascript

I have the following structure.

A geometry file that declares some functions

```
function line(p1, p2){ 
}

//etc
```

An analysis.js that contains my model. It uses functions from geometry.js

```
function Downs(){
}

Downs.prototype.findSth = function (){
    //uses line
    line1 = line(p1, p2);
}
```

And In my html file I declare them with the following sequence

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/geometry.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../js/analysis.js"></script>
```

the directory tree is

```
.
├── css
│   └── main.css
├── html
│   └── orthocal.html
├── js
│   ├── analysis.js
│   ├── geometry.js
│   ├── kineticjs_source.js
│   ├── kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js
│   ├── main.js
│   └── orthodontist.js
├── media
│   ├── Praxisrundgang-R FRS.jpg
│   └── proline_ap_pa_ceph__17839_1340650087_1280_1280.png
```

But I get a reference error that line is not defined. In my Network tab in chrome's dev console, geometry.js is loaded but without content. I mean I don't get an error status code but no content in the preview. Why is it not loading?

Comment: chrome  36.0.1985.143 Linux

Comment: Ah, reading fail. You do mention it. Apologies. I don't know why then. Can you confirm with `curl` that the file is being served correctly?

Comment: No problem. Issue with Firefox too.

Comment: What happens when you open this js file (by its URL) in another tab directly?

Comment: Is `anaylysis.js` a typo?

Comment: It showed blank page. Now it loads the content but I still get a reference error...

Comment: Force-refresh the page (`Ctrl` + `F5` on Windows machines)

Comment: @Cerbrus I did, but I still get that reference error....:(

Comment: Damn....One bracket at the end of a function, But it showed the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input " only after a lot of refreshes. It works now. Thank you all!